# Suggestions for web deployment of prototype

Tags: python, django

I have prototyped a system using python on linux. I am now designing the architecture to move to a web based system. I will use Django to serve public and private admin pages. I also need a service running, which will periodically run scripts, connect to the internet and allow API messaging with an admin user. Thus there will be 3 components : web server, api_service and database.

1) What is best mechanism for deploying a python api_service on the VM? My background is mainly C++/C# and I would have usually deployed a C#-written service on the same VM as the web server and used some sort of TCP messaging wrapper for the API. My admin API code will be ad hoc python scripts run from my machine to execute functionality in this service.

2) All my database code is written to an interface that presently uses flat-files. Any database suggestion? PostgreSQL, MongoDB, ...

Many thanks in advance for helpful suggestions. I am an ex-windows/C++/C# developer who now absolutely loves Python/Cython and needs a little help please ...

Answer (score 0):

Right, am answering my own question. Have done a fair bit of research since posting.

2) PostgreSQL seems a good choice. There seem to be no damning warnings against using it and there is much searchable help. I am therefore implementing concrete PostgreSQL classes to implement my serialization interfaces.

1) Rather than implement my own service in python that sits on a remote machine, I am going to use Celery. RabbitMQ will act as the distributed TCP message wrapper. I can put required functionality in python scripts on the VM that Celery can find and execute as tasks. I can run these Celery tasks in 3 ways. i) A web request through Django can queue a task. ii) I can manually queue a remote Celery task from my machine by running a python script. iii) I can use Celery Beat to schedule tasks periodically. This fits my needs perfectly as I have a handful of daily/periodic tasks that can be scheduled plus a few rare maintenance tasks that I can fire off from my machine.

To summarize then, where before I would have created a windows service that handled both incoming TCP commands and scheduled behaviour, I can use RabbitMQ, Celery, Celery Beat and python scripts that sit on the VM.

Hope this helps anybody with a similar 'how to get started' problem .....